# Need help on how to actually use Passport authentication strategy in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, passport.js

Suppose I have a script [like this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-fitbit/blob/master/examples/login/app.js), which uses a Passport authentication strategy with an Express backend. How would I use this script to actually make API function calls? I don't see any explicit examples in the linked project's [documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-fitbit) nor can I find anything in Passport.js's [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/). Thanks.

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean `use this script to actually make API function calls in another script`?

Comment: @AndrewVolchenko I guess it doesn't really have to be in another script, but suppose I simply want to display in EJS the number of steps a user has walked since signing up, as such: https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API-Get-Activity-Stats

Comment: does authentication functionality itself works?

Comment: @AndrewVolchenko It does.

Comment: Hey @JessicaD, what would you like to achieve? Passport will only help you to login users into your app using their fitbit credentials. If you want to perform other operations using the fitbit API, you need to use those credentials and then make calls to the API.

Comment: @Jobsamuel: I just want to know how to make calls to the API with the same kind of Passport setup I linked to.

Comment: Now I see @JessicaD. Let me type some code in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing that you know how to use passport, and you will figure it out what's the right Fitbit API endpoint (honestly, I'm don't know it). Said that, let me give an idea that might help you solve your problem:

```
// An awesome npm module (https://github.com/mikeal/request)
var request = require('request');

//
// 
// 

// An express route.
app.get('/activities', function (req, res) {
   if (req.user !== null) {

      // User is authenticated.
      getUserActivities(req.user.id, res);
    } else {

      // Redirect to login the user isn't authenticated.
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

// This function will make API calls to Fitbit
// using the User ID we got from the PassportJS
// authentication process.
function getUserActivities(id, res) {

// It will request from Fitbit User activities.
request('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/'+ id +'/activities/',
     function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            // If everything goes well.
            return res.send(body);
        } else {

            // If something wrong happens.
            return res.send(error);
        }
);

}
```

The goal of this example is to show you that you need to use **PassportJS** to get fitbit users ID, **then** use that id to make API calls to fitbit.

Answer (score 2):

After passport user serialization done, every request has `user` field, which contains information passed to `done` callback of `passport.serializeUser` method.

```
app.get('/userID', function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.json(req.user.id);
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Also, you have access to `session`

```
app.get('/auth/fitbit/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('fitbit', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        req.session.loggedInAt = Date.now();
        res.redirect('/');
});
```

Information stored in `session` available in all requests, while user is authenticated

```
app.get('/someroute', function (req, res) {
    // call to another service
    var url = 'http://superservice.com/' + req.user.id + '/' + req.session.loggedInAt
    http.get(url, function (_res) {
       res.send(_res.data)
    });
});
```