# EJS variable reference from Express showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Following a [lot of great help from user Jobsamuel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245214/4115525) I have been having some difficulty getting the data I am trying to get from an API call to appear in the browser:

```
// An express route.
app.get('/activities', function (req, res) {
   if (req.user !== null) {

      // User is authenticated.
      getUserActivities(req.user.id, res);
    } else {

      // Redirect to login the user isn't authenticated.
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
});


// This function will make API calls to Fitbit
// using the User ID we got from the PassportJS
// authentication process.
function getUserActivities(id, res) {

// It will request from Fitbit User activities.
request('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/'+ id +'/activities/',
     function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            // If everything goes well.

            return res.send(body);
        } else {

            // If something wrong happens.
            return res.send(error);
        }
      }
);

}
```

I want to show `body` on a webpage using EJS, which I have tried like this: `<%= this.body %>`. The page renders in the browser, but the variable shows as `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here? I assume this is just a syntax issue, but I feel as though I am missing a step.

EDIT: Code where I call `res.render()`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user}, {body : body});
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', { user: req.user });
});
```

EDIT 2: Relevant portion of `index.ejs`

```
<body>
<% if (!user) { %>
    <h2>Welcome! Please log in.</h2>
<% } else { %>
    <!-- <h2>Hello, <%= user.displayName %>.</h2> -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="blank"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="info">
        Output: <%= this.body %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% } %>
</body>
```

UPDATE: The problem still persists. I feel like giving up on this. Something has to be missing here, right?

Comment: Which template is your `<%= this.body %>` in? Is that template rendered on the front-end or are you doing `res.render()` on the server-side somewhere?

Comment: It's in `index.ejs`, which I have rendered on the server. I can post that code if it helps.

Comment: Ok and where are you calling `res.render('index')`? It sounds like you need to pass that `body` with something like `res.render('index', { body: body })` instead of `res.send(body)` which just sends the text to the browser and not through the template. Also you'll probably want to change `this.body` to just `body`.

Comment: You can only pass one object of variables to `render()`. Meaning you should use this: `res.render('index', { user: req.user, body: body});`. After that you just have to make sure you set `res.locals.body` in some middleware before that route, otherwise you should fetch `body` within that route, however you want do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the render part, you only have to send one object, with all you variables inside :

```
res.render('index', { user: req.user, body : body});
```

The variables `user`, and `body` will be sent to the template (**not** `this.body`)

**Template :**

```
Output: <%= body %>
```

So in your case, the '/' route needs to be changed to :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user}); //no need for the body variable which doesn't exist yet 
});
```

And you need the '/activities' route to use the index view, this time with a body variable, so you have to use res.render.

Also, you should send body or error as a callback to your function and do the whole thing like below :

```
app.get('/activities', function (req, res) {
   if (req.user !== null) {

      // User is authenticated.
      getUserActivities(req.user.id,function(body){
        res.render('index', { user: req.user, body : body}); //body will contain either body or err depending on what your function returned
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

function getUserActivities(id,callback) {
    request('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/'+ id +'/activities/',
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                callback(body);
            } else {
                callback(error);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**Explanation of res.render vs res.send**

res.send will forward the raw variable to your browser. If you need it to go through a view, you need to use res.render. So using res.send would be fine if you tried to query /activities via an AJAX call and handled the raw result on the client. See the documentation for [res.send](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) and [res.render](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render)

Comment: console.log(body) just before the res.send, does it have any content?

Comment: It does't look like anything prints under `app.get(...)`. Strange.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean. can you console.log(body), in the getUserActivities function (before callback)?

Comment: I mean when I print a literal string like 

app.get('/activities', function (req, res) {
     if (req.user !== null) {

        // User is authenticated.
        getUserActivities(req.user.id,function(body){
        console.log('BODY!!!');

It doesn't show anything.

Comment: Doing `res.render('index', { user: req.user, body : body});` now gives the error `ReferenceError: body is not defined at app.get.res.render.user`

Comment: in the app.get('/'), there's no need for body as it's not defined yet.

Comment: and my answer. Note that @mscdex already gave you this last hint

Comment: The problem though is that when I change to <%= body %> the while page fails to render and I get a ReferenceError saying that `body is not defined`

Comment: body may be a reserved name in ejs, try using another name